# Unable to load private key from file "/var/simplesamlphp/cert/saml.pem"

Tags: php, joomla, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I try to integrate simplesamlphp with Joomla, I am getting the following error when I get authorization in simplesamlphp idp

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
1 www/_include.php:17 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Unable to load private key from file "/var/simplesamlphp/cert/saml.pem"
Backtrace:
14 lib/SimpleSAML/Utils/Crypto.php:220 (SimpleSAML\Utils\Crypto::loadPrivateKey)
13 modules/saml/lib/Message.php:34 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Message::addSign)
12 modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:1094 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\IdP\SAML2::buildAssertion)
11 modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:54 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\IdP\SAML2::sendResponse)
10 [builtin] (call_user_func)
9 lib/SimpleSAML/IdP.php:287 (SimpleSAML\IdP::postAuthProc)
8 lib/SimpleSAML/IdP.php:333 (SimpleSAML\IdP::postAuth)
7 [builtin] (call_user_func)
6 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:230 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::loginCompleted)
5 [builtin] (call_user_func)
4 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:145 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::completeAuth)
3 modules/core/lib/Auth/UserPassBase.php:298 (SimpleSAML\Module\core\Auth\UserPassBase::handleLogin)
2 modules/core/www/loginuserpass.php:83 (require)
1 lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php:236 (SimpleSAML\Module::process)
0 www/module.php:9 (N/A)
```

I have installed simplesamlphp and I have configured SP and ISP in the same simplesamlphp installation. Among the configuration steps I created in the `cert` directory the files `saml.pem` and `saml.crt` as described in the [documentation](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp#section_4) using the command `openssl req -newkey rsa: 3072 -new -x509 -days 3652 -nodes -out saml.crt -keyout saml.pem` this while being located in the `/cert` directory.

In joomla when executing the following code

```
require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');

$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');

$as->requireAuth(); // <-- 

$attributes = $as->getAttributes();

print_r($attributes);

die();
```

The simplesamlphp idp form is opened requesting the credentials, when authorizing me it sends me the error described above

I welcome your comments

Comment: Does the web server user have permissions to read those files?

Comment: Thanks for answering Kellen, in fact that turned out to be the problem, apply chmod 755 to / cert directory and that solved the problem.

Comment: Please do not abandon this page.  Please either retract your question, or find a duplicate that informs researchers about file permissions.  You might like to join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange if you are doing Joomla development.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to go into the 
`website/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/config/config.php` file and adjust the directory from where the certs are read from.

This is the very top of the file.

```
$config = array(

'baseurlpath' => 'http://website.localdev/',
'certdir' => 'certs/',
'loggingdir' => 'log/',
'datadir' => 'data/',
```

Initially this was set to `cert/`, and the directory I had created was `certs/`

Answer (score 0):

The original permissions, when you follow the procedure, are the following :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1773 avril 27 21:13 saml.crt
-rw-------  1 root root 2484 avril 27 21:12 saml.pem
```

Which is NOT good, since the web server is running with uid/gid `www-data/www-data`.

You can fix it, giving the minimum permissions required : allowing group read access to www-data :

```
$ sudo chown :www-data saml.pem
$ sudo chmod g+r saml.pem
```